# Bash script giving error when trying to run python pip

Tags: bash, scripts, python

I've created a custom GitHub Action with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8 mypy isort
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `entrypoint.sh` file is simple enough:

```
#!/bin/bash

...

$(python3 -m pip install -r $9 --no-cache-dir)

...
```

The offending line above gives an error saying:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 44: Collecting: command not found
```

The GitHub Action completes fine and even though the line raises this error it still executes. Does anyone have any insight on why this is happening and how to solve this?

---

**Attempted solution #1:**

Changing `pip` to `pip3` in the line gives an error saying `pip3` is not installed and the whole workflow fails to complete, where before it completed with no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `python3 -m pip install -r $9 --no-cache-dir` indeed ran fine.

It's output probably began with:

```
Collecting PACKAGE_NAME
```

But you didn't see this because for some reason you wrapped it with `$()`, which means "Don't show the output, execute it."

And `Collecting` is not a command, which is why it wasn't found!